# Java, output file to method

Tags: java

here is the new code, thanks to the gentleman the helped clarify how to close a file stream. I changed the code so that my functions call the file name now and then return a double. Looks good. I'm not if the files are even necessary as a parameter because the program worked without it but the directions I was given specified that each function should call the file(the second function calculateStandardDeviation should call a file and the mean). I think it all works. Thanks again.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Lab04
{

    private static Scanner inFile;
    private static Scanner open;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException

    {

        inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));

        System.out.print("Input: ");

        while(inFile.hasNextInt())
        {
            int input = inFile.nextInt();
            System.out.print(input + " ");
        }

        inFile.close();
        inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));

        File main = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner open = new Scanner(main);

        double mean = computeMean(open.nextDouble());
        System.out.print("\nMean: "); 
        System.out.printf(String.format("%.2f", mean));

        inFile.close();
        inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));

        double standard = computeStandardDeviation(open.nextDouble(), mean);
        System.out.printf("\nStandard Deviation: ");
        System.out.printf(String.format("%.2f", standard) + "\n");
    }

    private static double computeMean(double mean)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            sum += inFile.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        while(inFile.hasNextInt());
        mean = (double) sum/i;
        return mean;
    }

    private static double computeStandardDeviation(double add, double mean)
    {
        add = 0;
        double summation = 0;
        int n = 0;
        while(inFile.hasNextInt())
        {
            double calc = (inFile.nextInt() - mean);
            add = Math.pow(calc, 2.0);
            summation += add;
            n++;
        }
        return Math.sqrt(summation/n);
    }
}
```

Comment: *The second function does run at all* ?  It does or it **doesn't**?

Comment: I definitely researched this. My book and online have helped tremendously but I am stuck here. Obviously I am a beginner. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should cut your question into several simple ones. For instance, how do I read array (or list) of double values from file. Then, how do I calculate mean for array of doubles. Many of simple questions were already answered before many times (just google to check). You might even solve your problem without even asking new question.

Comment: Yes @karphillip. I meant to write that the second function does not run at all I believe. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @rsutormin right. Well its not an array. Its just a file I need to read from. Also I have asked these questions and they have been answered. So the questions you're suggesting I ask are not relevant sorry. My program compiles and reads the list of double values from the file. I need help with calling a function that accepts a file name mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am basing my answer on the original information that you are reading from a file of integers, not, as your code would suggest doubles, e.g. `while(inFile.hasNextDouble()){...` Also, there are a number of suggestions that I must make in order for this program to function as (I think) it was intended; I am going to go in order from the top. Have some patience, as I have included a copy of working code at the bottom that is as close to the provided as is possible.

1. In the interest of following conventions, please do not use `package lab04.java;` Anything else, such as  `package lab04;` will suffice.
2. `import java.lang.*;` is an unused import
3. There is no need to nullify your scanner and call `System.gc();` You already redeclare your scanner when you run `inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));` Just close the scanner first.
4. Review the code sample below. Understand that you are getting the next (first, because we redeclare inFile) double from a scanner of a "file with integers in it." You name this double "file." Then, you print the return value of the computeMean method, into which you are passing "file."

   ```
   double file = inFile.nextDouble();
   System.out.printf("Mean: " + computeMean(file));
   ```
5. Your computeMean method is almost correct as is (below); however, you do not need the `double mean` parameter. Based on this method declaration and your declaration for computeStandardDeviation, you need to understand one of two things. (A) These methods are neither recursive nor do they need to be. (B) The return type is what you are putting before the method name, not what is in parenthesis. What is in parenthesis is data provided to the method. In this case, computeMean only needs the integers in input.txt, which is parsed by your scanner, inFile. Because inFile is a class variable, computeMean already has access to it. Now, in the body of computeMean, we return to the same issue as in (4), i.e. you are requesting the next double in a file of integers. The final code sample reflects the changes necessary to fix computeMean and the corresponding modifications to computeStandardDeviation.

```
        public static double computeMean(double mean)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double i = 0;
        do
        {
            sum += inFile.nextDouble();
            i++;
        }
        while(inFile.hasNextDouble());
        mean = sum/i;
        return mean;
    }
```

6. Your methods should function regardless of the conditions under which they are executed; however, in order to preserve the originality of your work, I have left them as designed. It would be better to pass computeMean and computeStandardDeviation a file and have each method initialize a scanner.

```
    package lab04;

    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class Lab04
    {

        private static Scanner inFile;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
        {

            inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));

            System.out.print("Input: ");

            while(inFile.hasNextInt())
            {
                int input = inFile.nextInt();
                System.out.print(input + " ");
            }

            inFile.close();
            inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));

            double mean = computeMean();
            System.out.print("\nMean: " + mean);

            inFile.close();
            inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));

            System.out.print("\nStandard Deviation: " + computeStandardDeviation(mean));
        }

        private static double computeMean()
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                sum += inFile.nextInt();
                i++;
            }
            while(inFile.hasNextInt());
            double mean = (double) sum/i;
            return mean;
        }

        private static double computeStandardDeviation(double mean)
        {
            double add = 0;
            double summation = 0;
            int n = 0;
            while(inFile.hasNextInt())
            {
                double calc = (inFile.nextInt() - mean);
                add = Math.pow(calc, 2.0);
                summation += add;
                n++;
            }
            return Math.sqrt(summation/n);
        }
    }
```

7. **(update)** - *created one file and passed the file as an argument, as suggested in (6)*

```
    package lab04;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    public class Lab04 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            File file = new File("input.txt");
            System.out.println("Input: ");
            print(file);
            System.out.print("\nMean: " + computeMean(file));
            System.out.print("\nStandard Deviation: " + computeStandardDeviation(file));
        }

        private static void print(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
            while(inFile.hasNextInt())
            {
                int input = inFile.nextInt();
                System.out.print(input + " ");
            }
            inFile.close();
        }

        private static double computeMean(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
            int sum = 0;
            int i = 0;
            do {
                sum += inFile.nextInt();
                i++;
            } while(inFile.hasNextInt());
            inFile.close();
            double mean = (double) sum/i;
            return mean;
        }

        private static double computeStandardDeviation(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
            double add = 0;
            double summation = 0;
            int n = 0;
            while(inFile.hasNextInt()) {
                double calc = (inFile.nextInt() - computeMean(file));
                add = Math.pow(calc, 2.0);
                summation += add;
                n++;
            }
            inFile.close();
            return Math.sqrt(summation/n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very insightful and helpful. I understand was I was confused about now. Thanks.

Comment: Now, it regards to what you said about passing a file to each method and then having each method initialize a scanner.. How would I create a file class that could be passed to my method when my return type is a double. Also for the computeStandardDeviation function would I need to use two parameters, one to pass the file and another to pass the mean score. I am not sure how to arrange this or what the appropriate file class would be.

Comment: I changed the code and I am very close. For some reason my numbers are coming out slightly off..

Comment: Your method declaration would look like `private static double computeMean(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {...` Per requested, we are passing files here; however, realize that you were using a FileReader (although it was unnecessary). As for how to create the file, look at my update (7). Also, notice that computeStandardDeviation does not need the mean parameter, because it calls computeMean(file) inside the method body. Otherwise, computeStandardDeviation is dependent on the file argument being the same (unchanged) file as the file passed to computeMean.

Comment: Excellent work. I learned a lot from this, I appreciate your help. Thanks for your time.